# DNS, DHCP, FILESERVER transition from W2003 to W2008R2 DC's

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, migration

We have a stable Windows 2003 Standard network.

W2003 DC1 on x.x.x.10 - DC, DNS, DHCP, FILESERVER

We are upgrading the network, and have a second server Windows 2008 R2 ready for insertion.

W2008R2 DC2 on x.x.x.20 - DC

For the transition, I plan to:

a) Prepare the Active Directory environment, using adprep.exe

b) Install the DC2 and promote it, using dcpromo.exe

c) Then transfer the FSMO roles to DC2.

What I need to do next is the bit I'm struggling with..

d) Transfer the DNS to DC2
e) Transfer DHCP to DC2 
f) Transfer FILESERVER to DC2

g) Take DC1 down
h) Install W2008R2 from scratch
i) Bring DC1 back up as DC
j) Transfer FILESERVER back to DC1.

Since all the current workstations are looking to x.x.x.10 for the DNS, I don't know how to go about transferring the DNS. Presumably I'll have to change the DNS setup on the workstataions to point at DC2?

I think you can backup DHCP to an export file, and then import it on DC2 - but I'm not 100% sure.

I'm not entirely sure how I'm going to shift fileserving from one server and back again. The transition is taking place over a weekend, so perhaps I can just backup all the file systems, make the transition and then re-instate them on DC1 and the ACL's will remain the same.

So  my questions are:

1) How do I transfer DNS from DC1 to DC2?

2) How do I transfer DHCP from DC1 to DC2?

3) Can I hold off transferring FILESERVER functionality, until DC1 is back up as a W2008R2 DC, and will the AD take care of ACL's?

If anyone has advice or help in how to go about performing this transfer and upgrade it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why 2008r2 and not go to a current windows version directly?

Comment: @TomTom we've got the hardware/software for w2008R2 ready to roll. Not sure we've got the funding to go the extra, and get w2012, sadly.

Comment: Sucks. Depending on your license, though, it may be free.

Comment: When you have finished, do you intend to keep the two servers in production? If so, you can configure all of those services for redundancy.

Comment: @hmallet Yes, both servers will be in production.

Answer (score 0):

1. DNS Transfer should be easy, you should be able to add the DNS Service to the new DC as long as your zones are AD integrated they will be added to the new DNS Server.  The hard part is changing the clients DNS settings.
2. DHCP Transfer is done by exporting the Zones and reimporting on the new server, Article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281626
3. Mircosoft also makes a File Server transfer tool.  I have never used it so I cannot speak to specifics, but the latest version is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10268